# Installing dlib python module getting segfault

Tags: python, boost, installation, cmake, dlib

I'm trying to install the dlib python module but every time I try to import it I get a segfault and python crashes like this.

```
└[~/Devspace/dlib]> python 
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
[1]    50326 segmentation fault  python
```

I don't get any other error message so I'm not sure what to do to troubleshoot this. I installed boost and python (and symlinked over system python) using homebrew on OS X. I've been searching around and I saw that this is normally caused by incompatible versions of boost and python, which could be caused by using homebrew versions of libraries with system python. I'm fairly certain this is the cause somehow but CMake tells me this when compiling

```
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost version: 1.59.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found suitable version "2.7.10", minimum required is "2.6")
-- USING BOOST_LIBS: /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
-- USING PYTHON_LIBS: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
-- Enabling SSE4 instructions
 *****************************************************************************
```

So I know that thte python libs and boost libs are both coming from the homebrew managed `/usr/local/bin` and not the system managed `/usr/bin/`. Make finishes fine and returns a success and even seems to install everything just fine.

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/tools/python/../../python_examples/dlib.so
Populating the distribution directory /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib ...
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/correlation_tracker.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/correlation_tracker.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/dlib.so -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/dlib.so.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/face_detector.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/face_detector.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/face_landmark_detection.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/face_landmark_detection.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/find_candidate_object_locations.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/find_candidate_object_locations.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/max_cost_assignment.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/max_cost_assignment.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/sequence_segmenter.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/sequence_segmenter.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/svm_rank.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/svm_rank.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/svm_struct.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/svm_struct.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/train_object_detector.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/train_object_detector.py.
Copying file /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./python_examples/train_shape_predictor.py -> /Users/gabriel/Devspace/dlib/./dist/dlib/examples/train_shape_predictor.py.
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib
copying dist/dlib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib
running egg_info
creating dist/dlib.egg-info
writing dist/dlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dist/dlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to dist/dlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'dist/dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'dist/dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '**' found under directory 'dlib/build'
warning: no files found matching '*.bat' under directory 'python_examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '**' found under directory 'python_examples/build'
writing manifest file 'dist/dlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
copying dist/dlib/dlib.so -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib
creating build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/correlation_tracker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/face_detector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/face_landmark_detection.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/find_candidate_object_locations.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/max_cost_assignment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/sequence_segmenter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/svm_rank.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/svm_struct.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/train_object_detector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
copying dist/dlib/examples/train_shape_predictor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.11-x86_64-2.7/dlib/examples
running build_ext
```

After that it is installed in my python site packages and can be seen with pip

```
└[~/Devspace/dlib]> pip freeze      
appnope==0.1.0
colorama==0.3.3
cv2==1.0
cycler==0.9.0
decorator==4.0.4
dlib==18.18.99
gnureadline==6.3.3
imutils==0.3
```

but it always causes a segfault if I try and import it. I am using the included `setup.py` to install and was thinking I may need to run CMake myself if the python/boost didn't match but they look fine to me. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How should a segfault be related to CMake?

Comment: @usr1234567 From what I read the segfault is caused by the source being compiled against incompatible library versions. So like if Cmake compiles using boost-python for python 3 with the python 2 interpreter or something but that doesn't look like that's happening with me. But then again I'm not really sure which is why I'm trying to get help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977142/pass-custom-cmake-flags-to-pip-when-building-module-that-needs-compiled-code/35343342#35343342). I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/pull/77) that takes care of it for me on OS X with brewed Python.