# Pass custom CMake flags to pip when building module that needs compiled code

Tags: python, cmake, pip

I'm currently installing a module that requires compiled code (dlib) using pip. Pip runs setup.py which runs cmake and complies the code. Is there a way to pass custom cmake flags to pip when specifying a module to install or is my only option to run cmake manually? I wasn't really able to find much about this searching around.

Comment: Share some code, a minimal running example would be nice. Currently we can only guess what you do.

Comment: when you build dlib and the python binding, the default is `python setup.py install`. but, this will build a broken dlib.so if you are on os x and using virtualenv. if you manually invoke cmake with `cmake ../tools/python -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib`, you successfully link a dlib.so, but the rest of the setup.py setup is not done. So, the OP question is appropriate: how to pass cmake variables through setup.py?

Comment: i ended up making a small change to setup.py for building on OS X with a brewed python and virtualenv. i'll see about creating a pull request for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [PR](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/pull/77) works for me, on OS X using a brewed Python 2.7.11.